# Cannot run Espresso with dynamicFeatures

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

When I am trying to run instrumented unit tests, I have a Manifest merging issue with Dynamic Features enabled.

I tried adding the modules as "androidTestImplementation project" but since they are "features" not "modules" it does not work. Anyway, I feel that this is a step too late because adding Dynamic Features already fails at this point. This is the Manifest merging issue:

```
insertion/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/manifestMerger.xml  
Android resource linking failed
```

build.gradle

```
    android {
    ...
    dynamicFeatures = [":feature1", ":feature2"]
    }
```

Did someone else had the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding app dependency also for androidTest in my dynamic feature module

```
implementation project(':app')
androidTestImplementation project(':app')
```